# How to write clean url htaccess in nginx 0.7.65

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am getting 404 error , after converting htaccess of apache to nginx , bellow is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Please help me , i am learnet

Answer (score 1):

edit your nginx.conf and add this line in you vhost

```
     location / 
    { 
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    { 
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break; 
    } 
    }
```

Comment: IS THERE any other method to do this?

Comment: in nginx there is nothing like .htaccess... but you need to edit nginx.conf may be located in /etc/nginx.conf if installed using software package manager like yum or apt-get.. if you installed using source than default location for nginx.conf will be /usr/local/nginx/etc/nginx.conf